# What exactly is a translation unit in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The commonly used definition of a *translation unit* is what comes after preprocessing (header files inclusions, macros, etc along with the source file). This definition is reasonably clear and the C standard, 5.1.1.1, C11, says:

> A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard. A source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing directive `#include` is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit.

Reading the first sentence more closely:

> A C program need not all be translated at the same time.

which implies (to my reading), a C program *can* be translated at the same without necessarily splitting them into multiple preprocessing source files.
Also at the end of the same paragraph, the standard says:

> Translation units may be separately translated and then later linked to produce an executable program.

which can be (and typically is) interpreted as compiling individual object files and then finally linking them to produce a single executable program. However, if one can make a question out of the above statement and ask: does it mean an implementation is free to consider multiple source files as a single translation unit, especially for an invocation like:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c -o out
```

where the compiler has access to the entire source?

In particular, if an implementation treats `file1.c` + `file2.c` (above) as a single translation unit, can it be considered non-conforming?

Comment: The Standard has literally nothing to say about GCC's interpretation of its command-line arguments. That's squarely out of the scope of ISO C, so it's not even implementation-defined within the meaning of the Standard.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to write conforming code that will compile and link cleanly as long as the two files are treated as separate translation units, but that will fail to compile if they're treated as one TU  For example, the files could each define a static function with the same name; if treated as a single TU, the composite would have that function multiply defined.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist GCC (plus libraries, platform etc) is an *implementation* and whether, if at all, GCC (or any compiler) doing so would be considered as non-conforming is the question. In fact, there's nothing in the question that asks about GCC's behaviour other using it as an example for the compilation command.

Comment: But @usr, whether `gcc file1.c file2.c` causes GCC to consider them a single TU or not is entirely up to GCC. I mean, `cat file1.c file2.c` concatenates them; If `gcc` felt like providing `cat`-like functionality it would be legitimate for it to do that. The user manual could then document that choice. A C compiler could still exist within a context where the concept of a "file" resident in a "filesystem" does not exist. The Standard only chose to **call** these "units" _files_. It doesn't require them to actually **be** files in the common understanding of the term.

Answer (score 14):

In the second line you quoted:

> The text of the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard

If there are two source files then there are two preprocessing files, and therefore two preprocessing translation units, and therefore two translation units. One corresponding to each source file.

The standard doesn't define *source file*. I guess the compiler could say "I'm making up my own version of 'source file' by declaring that `file1.c` and `file2.c` are not source files after all!" and concatenate them, but this would be at odds with programmer expectations.  I think you would have a hard time arguing that `file1.c` is not a source file.

Comment: The compiler cannot do that arbitrarily. It could document the behaviour, in which case the careful programmer who always reads documentation before deploying a new compiler would already have adjusted their expectations (or gone back to a compiler with more conventional behaviour).

Comment: @rici the question was whether it would violate the standard if the compiler did that;   if you interpret the words "source file" in the standard to mean "the result of concatenating files indicated by commandline arguments" then the compiler could do that.

Comment: i think that it would be legitimate for a compiler to define source file as the concatenation of the arguments. But it is implementation-defined behaviour so it is only legitimate if documented. Equally, a more conventional compiler must specify that each named file in the command line is treated as a separate translation unit, and you will probably find that statement if you look for it.

Comment: well... I actually saw `#include "whatever.cpp"` so... yeah... that can happen...

Comment: If the command line would have been `gcc file1.c + file2.c -o out`, there would be little objection to treating the concatenation as a single _source file_ for Standard purposes. But as we agree that command line syntax is not standardized, it's impossible to argue whether `gcc file1.c file2.c -o out` is _also_ a concatenation.

Comment: This is a fairly convincing argument. But is there any text in the C standard that prohibits it either directly or implicitly?

Answer (score 13):

> However, if one can makes a question out of the above statement and ask: does it mean an implementation is free to consider multiple source files as a single translation unit

No. The definition is clear:

> **A** source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit.

A translation unit is the result of preprocessing **one** source file and its includes. The fact that you might translate two translation units at the same time doesn't mean you can treat them as one translation unit.

Answer (score 7):

Compilers are free to translate several source files at the same time, but they cannot change their semantics.

Translating several files together will likely be somewhat faster (because the compiler starts only once) and will permit better whole program optimization: Source code of called functions in other translation units is then available at the point of call from other translation units. The compiler can inspect the called code and use the information, much as it can with a single translation unit. [From the gcc 6.3.0 manual:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

> The compiler performs optimization based on the knowledge it has of the program. Compiling
>   multiple files at once to a single output file mode allows the compiler to use **information**
>   gained **from all of the files** when compiling each of them.

Called functions can be inspected for absence of aliasing, factual const-ness of pointed-to objects etc., enabling the compiler to perform optimizations which would be wrong in the general case.

And, of course, such functions can be inlined.

But there are semantics of (preprocessing) translation units (which correspond to source files after preprocessing, per your standard quote) which the compiler must respect. @Malcolm mentioned one, file-static variables. My gut feeling is that there may be other, more subtle issues concerning declarations and declaration order.

Another obvious source code scope issue concerns defines. From the n1570 draft, 6.10.3.5:

> A macro definition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding #undef
>   directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) **until the end of the preprocessing
>   translation unit.**

Both issues forbid simple C source file concatenation; the compiler must additionally apply some rudimentary logic.

Answer (score 5):

A translation unit means a dot C file. To all intents and purposes, including its associated dot h includes. Rarely, `#include` directives are used to add other file types or other dot C files.

Static variables are visible only within the translation unit. It's very common to have a few public functions with external linkage and many static functions and data items to support. So a C translation unit is a bit like a singleton C++ class. If the compiler doesn't handle static correctly it is non-conforming.

Typically one object file is created for each translation unit, and they are then linked by the linker. That's not actually mandated by the standard, but is the natural and obvious way to do things in an environment where files are cheap to create and compiling is relatively slow.

Comment: To be provocative: Today I'd argue that compiling is relatively fast (how many cores?) but file creation is expensive ;-). Actually, that may have been the case all along : I used to compile on a RAM disk on my Atari ST because the mass storage was a floppy disk.