# Difference between using extern variable or not using extern variable

Tags: c, variables, header, extern

I have a bit confusion about the variable definition and declaration using "extern" keyword. Assuming I want a variable 'timer' can be used in multiple c files. Then I can:

On c1.h

```
int timer;
```

Then on c1.c

```
#include "c1.h"
void timer_increase() {
    timer++
}
```

Then on c2.c

```
#include "c1.h"
void print_timer() {
    printf("%d", timer);
}
```

However, when I using extern variable:

On c1.h

```
extern int timer;
```

Then on c1.c

```
#include "c1.h"
int timer;
void timer_increase() {
    timer++
}
```

Then on c2.c

```
#include "c1.h"
void print_timer() {
    printf("%d", timer);
}
```

Both scripts work fine and I cannot see any reason that I have to used extern to declare a variable. Can anyone gives me any hints?

Comment: There are no scripts in C. All your code samples are programs. You also have a missing semicolon in `c1.c`.

Comment: Please read this answer by [Storyteller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511662/918959). Basically that  your program works is because the C implementation is using the common extension J.5.11, but your code is not strictly-conforming. Not all implementations do support J.5.11 - for example the Visual C++'s C compiler does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the variable once and declare it in header so that rest of the files have visibility to the variable.

When you don't use `extern` in the header file, everytime you are defining the same variable in multiple files.

Comment: Thanks for that!