# error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type

Tags: c

In a header file, `foo.h`, I have something like:

```c
extern const int array_foo[];
```

Then in a source file, `foo.c`, I have something like:

```c
const int array_foo[] = {1 , 2, 3};
```

then in the `main.c` I have somehting like:

```c
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    sizeof(array_foo);
    return 0;
}
```

However, compiling yields the error:

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type `const int[]`
```

I have it defined in the `foo.c` file, so why is the compiler complaining that it doesn't know what the array is?

Comment: `main` sees `array_foo` as `extern int array_foo[];` . It has no idea what the size is, and that is *exactly* what the error is reporting. What is your question, btw?

Comment: @WhozCraig Why doesn't the compiler see the defined array in the foo.c file?

Comment: Because you included the .h file (as you should), not the .c file. If it did see `extern const int array_foo[] = {1 , 2, 3};`, you'd end up with two arrays with the same name, one in `main.o` and one in `foo.o`.

Comment: @ikegami but when you compile and link, wont the compiler then be able to see the defined array?

Comment: Because `foo.c` isn't what the compiler is compiling.`foo.c` is a separate [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262802/what-exactly-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) from `main.c` When the compiler compiles `main.c` all it knows about `array_foo` is what is *declared* in that header. When it compiles `foo.c` it knows both the declaration (from the header) *and* the formal definition.

Comment: When you link, yes. But you didn't get that far. There was a compilation error. `sizeof` is evaluated a compile-time, and the size of its operand isn't available.

Comment: @ikegami But the issue is that I am compiling and linking main.c, and foo.c, and its throwing that error.

Comment: @ikegami by "But you didn't get that far" are you saying that there is another error that is preventing compilation, and thus linking so it cant see the definition of array_foo?

Comment: Where is array_foo defined? Is this all of the code?

Comment: @LayneBernardo array_foo is defined in foo.c is it not?

Comment: @Kalcifer Ah you are right actually, for some reason I was thinking that `extern` only declared a variable and that you needed to define it somewhere without the `extern` keyword. But apparently that's not the case. @WhozCraig is correct. I don't think the compiler can know the size of the array in main.c.

Comment: There are two main phases of making a program. The compiler phase runs first. The compiler sees only one .c file at a time. Once all the .c files are combined, the linker phase runs. The linker sees all of the .c files. The error you're getting is coming from the compiler. It's important to know about these phases and what happens in each phase. (And what each phase "knows".)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you cant define a variable in a second source file...?

Comment: You can define a variable in a separate file, as long as you declare it in a place that other files can see. In your case, you declared "There is an array of integers called `array_foo` but I'm not going to tell you how big the array is." This is legal in C. What is not legal is then asking, "That thing that I didn't tell you how big it is? Yeah, so how big is it?"

Comment: @RaymondChen "as long as you declare it in a place that other files can see" > Okay, then the new question would be: then wouldn't the only place that main.c could see defined things is from within main.c? It seems strange to me that you can only use a defined variable from within the file that it has been defined in.

Comment: You can use a variable anywhere it has been declared. So `main.c` can use `array_foo` because you declared it in `foo.h` (which `main.c` includes). However, your declaration was "incomplete": Since you didn't say how many elements are in the array, you cannot ask how big it is. (You can still use the variable in other ways.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Doesn't defining an array with x elements, then also set the size of the array to x?

Comment: The definition is in `foo.c`, not `main.c`. So `foo.c` is allowed to do `sizeof(array_foo)`. But `main.c` is not.

Comment: The point of the header file is to let main.c know what types, functions, etc, things are in foo.c. It doesn't include information like the size of the array, because the actual array is defined in a foo.c, which is not included in main.c. What is your goal here, btw?

Comment: Re "*are you saying that there is another error that is preventing compilation*", No, I'm talking about the error you mentioned.

Comment: Re "*So if I understand correctly, you cant define a variable in a second source file...?*", No. The problem is that you have code that needs the size of a variable, but the size of the variable is not available. `const int array_foo[]; sizeof(array_foo)` will never work, no matter how many files you have. otoh, `extern const int array_foo[3]; sizeof(array_foo)` does work fine.

Comment: Re "*Doesn't defining an array with x elements*", Where do you see *x* in `extern const int array_foo[];`???

Answer (score 1):

You were supposed to put in `foo.h` all the information that `main.c` needs to know about `array_foo`. But you didn't put its size in there. That's fine so long as `main.c` doesn't need to know that. But it does, so that's not fine.

The header file must include whatever other files need to know. You could include a prototype of a `get_size_of_array_foo` function in `foo.h`, implement it in `foo.c` and call it in `main.c` if you want. But the size won't be known at compile time because you can't rely on the compiler being able to look into `foo.c` when it compiles `main.c`.